# Calculate the total width of an element and add some extra pixel when it is hover using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jQuery script to calculate the total width of `ul` based on the size and number of the anchor links inside it (first it takes the width of each anchor tag and multiplies them with their number):

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
    /**
     * jQuery Accordion
     */
    $j('#accordion ul li a').hover(function() {
        // if the element is currently being animated (to a easeOut)...
        if ($j(this).is(':animated')) {
            $j(this).stop().animate({width: "310px"}, {duration: 450, easing:"easeOutQuad"});
        } else {
        // ease in quickly
            $j(this).stop().animate({width: "310px"}, {duration: 400, easing:"easeOutQuad"});
        }
        }, function () {
        // on hovering out, ease the element out
        if ($j(this).is(':animated')) {
            $j(this).stop().animate({width: "78px"}, {duration: 400, easing:"easeInOutQuad"})
        } else {
        // ease out slowly
        $j(this).stop('animated:').animate({width: "78px"}, {duration: 450, easing:"easeInOutQuad"});
        }
    });
    /**
     *  Calculate the size of all the images inside the Jquery Accordion
     */
    var customWidth = $j('#accordion ul li a').outerWidth(true);
    var customNumber = $j('#accordion ul li a').size();
    $j('#accordion ul').css("width", customWidth*customNumber);
    // add extra 78px if it is hovered
    $j("#accordion ul li a").hover(function(){$j('#accordion ul').css("width", (customWidth*customNumber)+78px);});
});
```

The last part is to add extra 78px to `ul` when an anchor tag is hovered it is hovered. For some reason is not working (if that line is added the width is not outputted).

Any suggestions?

html:

```
<div id="accordion">
        <ul>
            <?php // Create and run custom loop
                $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
                $custom_posts->query('post_type=page_content&page_sections=Slider (Front Page)');
                while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
            ?>
            <li class="landscapes"><?php the_content(); ?><></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$j("#accordion ul li a").hover(function(){$j('#accordion ul').css("width", (customWidth*customNumber+78) + 'px');})
```

Because you need to do a math expression (number + number) and then append a string.